# list all the databases and tables in nodejs either using loopback-datasource-juggler or jugglingdb

Tags: node.js, orm, loopbackjs, strongloop, jugglingdb

I am developing an strongloop-arc like tool on loopback (nodejs). To discover models from existing data-sources I need to list all databases and there tables to the user, from where user will select database and table to discover model.
What should I do to achieve the above requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer of my own question from here
 https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Database+discovery+API#DatabasediscoveryAPI-discoverModelDefinitions

from here I can discover all tables of database by giving database as parameter.